# Any ideas? CSV file lists

Tags: csv

Here is a sample data set containing information about unsuccessful email deliveries. Each row of the CSV file lists the reason returned from the recipient’s server. Using a common scripting language, parse the CSV file and list the top 10 most common reasons returned in descending order and the number of times each of these reasons occurred.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6E23-4OTB7aR05tR1FGbmRXMTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Well I know Ruby. I just don't know where to start in going about the problem? What do you think?

Comment: This may be overkill for you needs, but I'd tend to put all the data into a sqlite db using a script of your choice (Ruby has a gem, I'm sure of it), then using SQL this be as easy as breathing.